# Reshape dimensions in a tiff file

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, tiff

I am working on a code that would take my tif file of dimension [5,1024,1024,3] to reorder it to produce dimension of [5, 3, 1024, 1024]. [5,1024,1024,3] shows the dimension of [nplane x nY x nX x nchannels]. The goal is to get [nplane x nchannels x nY x nX ] or [5, 3, 1024, 1024] I am not sure what is the problem. The `resized_data` gives the correct dimension [5, 3, 1024, 1024].

```
import skimage.io
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from tifffile import imread, imwrite, imsave
from numpy import savetxt
data = skimage.io.imread('stack.tif')
print(data.shape)



# resizing file
resized_data = np.reshape(data, (5, 3, 1024, 1024))
print(resized_data.shape)


imwrite('resized_stack.tif', resized_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.transpose(data, (0, 3, 1, 2))` will move the data around so that the 4th axis is between the first two.

Comment: Thank you! I think that solved it!